# find the number of the rows from the first table whose column values are not in the second table in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have two tables called `"system"` and `"internal"` and it has columns `(name, ip, entry_no, allocate_no)`

i will join this two table by `name and ip`  and i want to get all the rows from table `"system"` whose `"entry_no"` is not there in the table `"internal"`

this is the query i was trying

```
    select s1.name, s1.ip, s1.entry_no, s1.allocate_no
from system s1 inner join internal as i1 
on s1.name=i1.name and s1.ip = i1.ip
where not exists (
select s2.entry_no
from system s2 inner join internal as i2 
on s2.name=i2.name and s2.ip = i2.ip and s2.entry_no=i2.entry_no
)

system (table)    

name ip entry_no allocate_no 

x     1   222    23

x     1   333    45

y     33  444    66

y     55  555    99

z     55  000    90
 
k    12   1155  99

internal (table)
name ip entry_no allocate_no 

x     1   222    23

x     1   666    45

y     33  444    66

y     33  888    66

y     55  777    99

m     55  000    90
```

here i want to write a query which should return

```
x     1   333    45

y     55  555    99
```

how can i achieve this somebody please help me

Comment: Considering the title states "mssql" I have taken the liberty to remove the tag [tag:mysql].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give all the rows of `system` that are not present in `internal`:

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM system AS s
LEFT JOIN internal AS i ON s.ip = i.ip AND s. entry_no = i.entry_no
WHERE i.ip IS NULL
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.. i have updated the question could you please check

Answer (score 1):

My first question is why you are applying `inner join` between `system` and `internal` table? When you apply `inner join`, you are asking sql server to give you only those row where the data matches between joined table.

If you are not familiar with JOINS, take a look at [Joins (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver15)

below query should work fine for you

```
select s.name, s.ip, s.entry_no, s.allocate 
from system s 
where not exists (select 1 from internal i where i.entry_no = s.entry_no and i.ip = s.ip)
```

Also, you can try [EXCEPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), which will give you records from `system` table that are not available in `internal` table.

```
select s.name, s.ip, s.entry_no, s.allocate 
from system s 

except

select i.name, i.ip, i.entry_no, i.allocate 
from internal i
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.. i have updated the question could you please check